# comparing values in multiple files

Tags: python, bash, shell, awk, text-processing

I have two files and each file has 3  columns and n number of rows (different number of rows in each file).

each looks like this:

```
file1
chr1    12  32 
chr1    14  30
chr3    10002  89000 
chrx    5678900   987654
```

and this:

```
file2
chr1    8   15
chr1    10  14
chr1    32  34
```

the second and third column in each file represent the starting and ending values while the first column is a name.

Hence, if the value in first column (of file 1) matches to the value in first column of file 2  and then script should compute if their exists an overlap (any degree of overlap of the value range in column 2 and 3 in file1 with value range in column 2 and 3 of file 2) of the range of value in second and third column from  file 1 in file2.

An output like this is desired:

```
regions from file1 present in file 2

chr1    12  32   present 
chr1    14  30   present 
chr3    10002  89000  absent
chrx    5678900   987654 absent
```

Any suggestions for awk manipulation or python script...please help.

Comment: @sebastian: normally when I have to compare the columns of 2 files I use diff or comm commands of shell. But since here I have a file and two additional columns as well, I am bit confused as to how I should proceed.

Answer (score 3):

1. Read `file2` to create a mapping: name -> intervals i.e., the result is: `ranges = {'chr1': [[8, 15], [10, 14], [32, 34]]}`. If there are many intervals for each name then as an optimization you could merge them: `ranges = {'chr1': [[8, 15], [32, 34]]}`.
2. Define `overlap(r1, r2)` function that returns whether two intervals `r1` and `r2` overlap. Specify whether the edges are included in the overlap.
3. For each line in `file1` find out whether the overlap is present and print appropriate output.